# how to find the random row of the csv file?

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to solve this for my assignment. I need to randomize a bunch of rows and print them, but can't seem to find out how to return the index of these rows that are randomized and chosen.
I have been searching on Stack Overflow and on other places, but everyone seems to be using pandas and nobody seems to use CSV and random which is a requirement for me this time around.
Can't really think of any solution

Comment: Open the CSV file. Use the file object's readlines() function which will give you a list which you can then pass to random.choice()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method prints line by line the first 10 lines of the rearranged csv:

```
from numpy import random

with open('loan_train.csv') as f:
    txt=f.readlines()
    lin=list(range(len(txt)))
    random.shuffle(lin)
    lin=lin[0:10]  # Change 10 to the number of lines you need
    for x in lin:
        print(txt[x])
```